# question on asset library - objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm currently working on asset library and i would like to find out how to do i get the url path from the ALAsset so that i can other things with it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs];
```

returns a dictionary that maps asset representations UTIs to URLs. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Comment: took the liberty of linking to the documentation.  Hope you don't mind.